# Laravel 5 - Middleware get user ID and send to controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, middleware

Hello guys !

I'm working on an API that has a middleware authenticating the user with a unique ID. After making sure that this user exists, I want to send his database ID to the controller coming next, whichever it is.

- Is that a good idea ? Or should I get that ID somehow after the middleware finished ?
- How do I do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that a good idea ? Or should I get that ID somehow after the middleware finished ?

It depends on what you want to do and how you routes are declared.
The routing is one of the first thing initialized by Laravel. You cannot pass parameter at run time (correct me if I'm wrong).

Plus, the controllers called after all midlewares has done their work.

I cannot garanty it's the more "beautiful" way to do this, but what i'm use to do is using `Session::flash()` or `Session::put()` when I want to pass parameters to my controllers at run time.

I use `Session::flash()` if the parameter has a one request life time, and `Session::put()` when I want the variable be more 'consistent' across the whole application.

I don't know if I am clear or not, tell me :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I don't think using sessins is the way for me - I just want to get some data in the middleware and then give that data to the controller that comes after !

Comment: Then, you can do the following in your middleware: $request->merge(['user_id' => $userId]); In your controller, you'll have to get Request $requst in the first param then do the following : $request->input('user_id'); But, there is no way to dynamically pass parameters to controllers at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as long as you don't send that ID passing through the HTTP protocol, you should be fine since the user won't be able to tamper with the data.

That said, if you are using Laravel's built-in `Auth` module, you should just do an `Auth::user()` call at the other controller and it will give you the authenticated user.

If that isn't an option, you should create a function in the other controller that accepts `$id` as a parameter. You can call that function from within the first controlling by constructing the second controller throug `$secondController = App->make(SecondController)` and then `$secondController->receiverFunction($id)`

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I'm not using Laravel's Auth, I'm using a custom Oauth server, so the middleware receives a token and gets me the user's unique ID used into the Oauth server. I then want to make a request to the users table to get the real auto incremented ID of that user. I can do that in the Middleware I guess, but then how to pass the value to the controller that comes after ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the currently-authenticated user available in your application, just add it your base controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

abstract class Controller {

    protected $auth;
    protected $currentUser;

    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->currentUser = $this->auth->user();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I'm not using Laravel's Auth, I'm using a custom Oauth server, so the middleware receives a token and gets me the user's unique ID used into the Oauth server. I then want to make a request to the users table to get the real auto incremented ID of that user. I can do that in the Middleware I guess, but then how to pass the value to the controller that comes after ?